# get the georeferenced points near me, with android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I have an android application that has some georeferenced places, and I can show them all or make the query to a specific one, but I want to consult those that are nearby within a radius of 1km from my location.
I think a between is used but I do not know how to do it.

```
criaderosMap = criaderoDao.queryBuilder()
            .where(CtlPlCriaderoDao.Properties.Latitud.isNotNull()).list();
```

It is the same as:

```
select * from ctlCriadero where latitud is no null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a query by your own. Following is one of the example.

```
    select
    latitud ,
    longitude,
    ( 3959 * acos(  cos( radians(37) )
                  * cos( radians( latitud ) )
                  * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(YourLongitude) )
                  + sin( radians(YourLatitude) ) * sin( radians( latitud ) )
                 )
    ) AS distance
FROM
    ctlCriadero
HAVING
    distance < 1000
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT
    0 , 50
```

Credit: @daroczig